# Are holomorphic functions integrable near essential singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

For simplicity let me state the question in this way.

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<2\}$. Suppose $f$ has an essential singularity at $0$. Do we have $$\int_{0<|z|<1}|f(z)|^p\,\mathrm{d}z=\infty,\qquad\text{for }0<p<2?$$

It can be shown using Hilbert space methods that when $p=2$ this is true (e.g., see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128883/area-integral-near-essential-singularity)). Then this is true for all $p\geq2$, since the disk has finite measure. However, I wonder whether this is true for $p<2$ also.

Comment: With complex functions we are usually concerned with path integrals, where the measure is given by arc length.  Here you seem to want an integral over a disk of the complex plane.  Accordingly some definition of what *measure* $dz$ is representing will be needed.

Comment: @hardmath Presumably it's $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @hardmath Yes it is the Lebesgue measure. This is just asking whether it lies in the appropriate Bergman spaces.

Answer (score 1):

As clarified in comments, this is using $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, which I prefer to denote as $dm(z)$ rather than $dz$.

Let's try $p=1$.  If $\Gamma_r$ is the positively-oriented circle of radius $r$ centred at $0$, the coefficient $a_k$ of the Laurent series for $f$ in the punctured disk is

$$ a_k = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\Gamma(r)} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi r^k} \int_0^{2\pi} f(r e^{i\theta}) e^{-ik\theta}\; d\theta$$
so that 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} |f(r e^{i\theta})|\; d\theta \ge \left| \int_0^{2\pi} f(re^{i\theta}) e^{-ik\theta}\; d\theta\right| = 2 \pi |a_k| r^k $$

and thus if $a_k \ne 0$ for some $k \le -2$ (which is certainly true if the singularity is essential), 
$$ \int_{0<|z|<1} |f(z)| \; dm(z) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r |f(re^{i\theta})| \; d\theta \; dr \ge 2 \pi |a_k| \int_0^1 r^{k+1}\; dr = \infty$$

Comment: Does it work for $0<p<1$?